I can't install msvc-runtime package. How can I get the msvc-runtime package?
When I insert the code(pip install msvc-runtime) in Powershell,
An error occur error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement msvc-runtime(from versions:none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for msvc-runtime
How can I get the msvc-runtime package??
I've been tried every way I can But I coudln't find a solution.
In Window Powershell, I tried pip install msvc-runtime, and I even tried setting environment variables through Googling to where the bin folder was, but it didn't work at all.
How can I get the msvc-runtime package??
I use vscode

I can install either cmd or powershell successfully by command pip install msvc-runtime.
I don't know for what reason you can't install, but I suppose you can download the .whl file directly in Pypi and install the package manually.
You could install the package by command pip install whlName.whl or pip install PATH/TO/whlName.whl after you installing the .whl file.

Ah-hah okay I understand it. Thanks!

Uh-oh sorry but I can't install the package you recommed because I don't know how to download in Pypi. Sorry. I'm begginer in this field.

Don't worry about being a beginner, you shouldn't need any special skills - browse the package entry on PyPI and you'll find how to download it by exploring and a trivial amount of thought
